# Guardar objeto em uma sessão em Swift(IOS)

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho uma classe e dentro uma subclasse

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Aluno: Mappable
{
    var ra:String!
    var senha:String!
    var nome:String!
    var cpf:String!
    var email:String!
    var matricula:Matricula!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        ra          <- map["Ra"]
        senha       <- map["Senha"]
        nome        <- map["Nome"]
        cpf         <- map["Cpf"]
        email       <- map["Email"]
        matricula   <- map["Matricula"]
    }
}


import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Matricula: Mappable
{
    var turma:String!
    var turno:String!
    var curriculo:String!
    var curso:Curso!
    var instituicao:Instituicao!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {}


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        turma       <- map["Turma"]
        turno       <- map["Turno"]
        curriculo   <- map["Curriculo"]
        curso       <- map["Curso"]
        instituicao <- map["Instituicao"]
    }
}
```

Depois de preencher esse objeto com um retorno de um JSON

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlBase, parameters: ["ra": idDoAluno, "senha": senhaDoAluno])
                .responseJSON { response in
                    let JSON = response.result.value as! NSDictionary;

                    self.aluno = Mapper<Aluno>().map(JSON["Dados"]!)!
```

Como faço para guardar esse objeto Aluno dentro de uma sessão(NSUserDefaults) para recuperar ele em outra view?

Comment: Voce precisa fazer a sua classe conform to NSCoding http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/5360/nscoding/19088/nscoding-compliant-class#t=201608110054445775751

Comment: se for pra passar esses dados entre telas sequenciais você pode passar via parâmetros de inicialização da tela (init)

Comment: Poderia demonstrar como ficaria esse código pois tenho uma subclasse Matrícula dentro da classe Aluno

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33194374/2303865

Comment: Então mas nesse exemplo os atributos da sua classe são todos String, como ficaria o código com uma classe que tenha outra classe como atributo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para salvar objetos customizados no `NSUserDefaults` você precisa fazer que a classe desse objeto implemente o **protocólo** `NSCoding`.

```
class Aluno: Mappable, NSCoding {
    // código aqui
}
```

Ao implementar esse **protocólo**, o mesmo irá exigir que você implemente duas funções:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if let ra = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("Ra") as? String {
        self.ra = ra
    }
    // Preencher todos os outros atributos, fazendo o cast para o tipo correspondente
}

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    if let ra = self.ra {
        aCoder.encodeObject(ra, forKey: "Ra")
    }
}
```

Para **salvar** o objeto

```
func saveAluno(aluno: Aluno) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archiveDataWithRootObject(aluno), forKey: "aluno")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Para **carregar** o objeto

```
func loadAluno() -> Aluno? {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let data = defaults.objectForKey("aluno") as? NSData {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! Aluno
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o que voocê quer é recuperar o objeto em outra view, utilizar o `NSUserDefaults` não é a melhor forma. Tente passá-lo definindo o objeto na view seguinte pelo `prepareForSegue`.

Exemplo:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            destination.aluno = meuObjetoAluno 
        }
     }
}
```

Cuidado também com a resposta assíncrona do Alamofire quando for montar o objeto. Se esse for seu problema, pode chamar a próxima view só depois de receber a resposta (colocar o push da view dentro do bloco da requisição) ou pode criar um callback para receber a resposta assíncrona.